# Why don't wildcard topics (#, +) work in Python paho MQTT Subscribe with retained messages?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, mqtt, wildcard, paho

I use paho.mqtt. And I send messange to topic `test/data/user1`

My Subscribe Client:

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client

host = 'myhost.com'
port = 1883
topic = 'test/data/#'
auth = {
    'username': 'myuser',
    'password': 'mypass'
}
client_id = 'python-mqtt-1'

def connect_mqtt() -> mqtt_client:
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.username_pw_set(**auth)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(host, port)
    return client


def subscribe(client: mqtt_client):
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print(f"Received `{msg.payload.decode()}` from `{msg.topic}` topic")

    client.subscribe(topic)
    client.on_message = on_message

def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    subscribe(client)
    client.loop_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

But I don't get my messange with `topic='test/data/#'`. If I use `topic='test/data/user1'`, I get my messange. Why is the wildcard theme not working?

My broker is RabbitMQ.

Comment: Your code should be a complete minimal test case. As it is with the import that code works perfectly with mosquitto with both `test/data/#` and `test/data/+`. You will need to supply more information about the broker you are using before we can say more.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. I use broker RabbitMQ

Comment: You may also want to check the return value of the call to subscribe for errors and the broker logs. But there is nothing (technically) wrong with that code or the paho library

Comment: can you try move subscribe function to on_connect callback?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt As I already said, there is nothing technically wrong with the code (there are some style issues around moving all the subscription code to be called from the `on_connect` callback) but it is not causing the problem the OP is having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently RabbitMQ itself doesn't support this feature.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/2556

Comment: That issue implies it only applies to retained messages